# How to Extract Data from a JTable filled by user in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have created a JTable using GUI Builder in NetBeans. It is Currently Having no data. The table is editable, and is Displayed in on a Panel. This Table is called passengerDetailsTable. Now I want users to Write data in its cells and after entering data, when they press submit, data should be extracted from table and available for processing. But I am unable to do it. 
I have written sample code to do above:

```
TableModel tm = passengerDetailsTable.getModel();
        Object o = tm.getValueAt(1,1);
        System.out.println(o.toString());
```

This code is triggered when I press submit button.

According to me It should print the value at cell(1,1). But it gives Null pointer exception. Please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I want users to Write data in its cells and after entering data,

Did the data get saved to the model?

See [Table Stop Editing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) for a way to make sure the data is save when you click a button.

If this doesn't help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem because we don't have enough information to keep guessing what you might be doing.

Comment: Thanks for this usefull link.Indeed my data was not saving to model. After Adding 
`if (passengerDetailsTable.isEditing())
    passengerDetailsTable.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();`
I was able to extract data.